# Does voting at match end do anything for the voted?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

I've been away from Heroes of the Storm for a while and now see that there is MVP and voting at the end of a match.  Does it ever do anything for people who get voted for, other than make them feel good (or bad)?

I searched Google and got saw some posts about people complaining about the system but they were from 2016, which I am guessing was around launch time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Players get nothing from the votes.

If someone gets enough votes, the announcer says "epic" or "legendary".  Getting the announcer to say this is my primary voting goal.

When playing vs AI, "epic" happens at 4 votes and "legendary" happens at 5 votes.

When playing vs humans, "epic" happens at 4 votes and "legendary" happens at 8 votes.  Note: this means the enemy team does have to vote for you to get "legendary".